# Visual Studio Code Git Issue

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, bitbucket.org, visual-studio-code

I'm running version 0.10.8 of Visual Studio Code in Xubuntu 14.04 x64, but used 0.8.4 before and didn't have this issue

When I try to push a commit to Bitbucket via VSCode, I get the following message:

> Error: Authentication failed on the git remote.

Specifically, the `Git Output` log states:

```
Missing ipc hook
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Where `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is my `username@bitbucket/repository` URL.

The same procedure in the previous version popped up a login screen where I entered my Bitbucket credentials and proceeded with the push. As a matter of fact, using the previous version in *the exact same folder*, still works as intended.

I already tried setting up a [credential helper](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html), but nothing changed.

My concern is if I'm doing anything wrong or it might be a bug. No bugs seem to be filed for this, but I might be wrong.

Should that not be the case, can anyone share some pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Joum, did you ever figure this out? I am on Visual Studio Code 0.10.8 on Debian Jessie and I get the same error when I try to push to Gitlab.

Comment: nope, nothing yet... got back to using 0.8 for the time being... :S